# BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController::update does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel (I'm using version 8) and I've been reviewing this error for a long time and I don't know what else to try.
I have a resource controller called ** UserController.php ** and I set the path in ** web.php ** as follows:
**Route::resource('usuarios', App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController::class);**

The resource paths are:
[image]

The user can enter their profile and modify their fields through this menu option that invokes the edit() method of the controller:
[image]

So far everything works very well, but when the user enters to edit in the ** edit.blade.php ** form, and selects the "update" button that calls the method ** update () ** of the controller, it jumps to me the error: BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\UsuarioController::update does not exist.

This is **edit.blade.php**:

```
@section('title', 'Mi Perfil')
 

@section('intro')  



@endsection

<br><br>
<style type="text/css">

h5 {text-align: center}
nav.navbar {
    background-color: #34495E;
}
</style>


 

@section('content0')

<div class="container3">

 <div class="bShadow3 bShadow-33">

    
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('usuarios.update',[Auth::user()->slug]) }}">
                        @method('PUT')
                        @csrf
                        <br>
                        <h5>Mi perfil</h5>
                           
                        <div class="form-group ml-5 mr-5">
                            <label for="name">{{ __('Nombre de usuario') }}</label>
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}" autocomplete="name" maxlength="30" autofocus placeholder="Introduce tu nombre de usuario" required>
                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group ml-5 mr-5">
                            <label for="name">{{ __('Dirección de correo:') }}</label><br>
                            <label for="email">{{Auth::user()->email}}</label>
                           
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col text-center">
                                <button type="submit"  class="btn2 mt-2 mb-3">
                                    {{ __('Actualizar') }}
                                </button>
                                <button type="default" class="btn2 mt-2 mb-3">
                                    {{ __('Cancelar') }}
                                </button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is **UsuarioController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Role;


class UsuarioController extends Controller
{
   
    public function __construct()
    {
        //permitir solo usuarios autenticados
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }



    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

   

    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

   
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        

    }

    
    public function show($id)
    {
         
    }

    
    public function edit($id)
    {
       $usuario=User::find($id);
       if ($usuario== null)
            return Redirect::to('usuario');
 
        return view('usuarios.edit')->with('id',$id);
   
    }

    

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
       $user = User::find($id);
       $user->name = Input::get('name');
       $user->email = Input::get('email');
       $user->password = Input::get('password');      
       $user->save();  
    }  

   
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }



    
}
```

If someone can give me a hand, I will thank them very much!

Comment: Why you need to call `Auth::user()->slug` on blade route method? You can simply get it on controller

Comment: What does the full controller file look like? What is the namespace? What is the filename, and where does it live in the file structure?

Comment: Hi, now I put all the complete code of UsuarioController.php

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, I already fixed the error.

I had two controllers using the same controller class and I was working with one and laravel with another.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly where the problem comes from but I think

1: change route

> {{route('usuarios.update',auth()->user()) }}

2:  It needs a model but you send slug usuarios/{usuario}